# Help in this complex numbers question involving fifth roots of unity and greatest integer function

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

**Question** :
If $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_5$ are the roots of the equation $z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1 = 0$, then the least value of $[|z_1+z_2|] + 1$ is ?
Here $[.]$ denotes greatest integer function.

I got the roots as the complex fifth roots of unity, by De Moivre's Theorem, but am not able to find the greatest integer part alone. Please help.

*Source : FIITJEE package, Section-II, Numerical Type, Q3*

Comment: If you were asked for the least possible value of $|z_1+z_2|,$ could you find the answer? How would you do it, and what would the answer be?

Comment: @Community : "As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking" : no it isn't.

Comment: Draw a diagram with the $z_k:=e^{2i\pi k/5}$ for $k=1,2,3,4$, then draw all the possible sums of "vectors" $z_p+z_q$, with a particular attention to (the norm of) $z_1+z_4$...